# TextBox display returns from RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, richtextbox

I am creating an invoice program for a small local company but have run into sort of a problem.  I have it setup so the invoice is printable by taking a screen shot of the application then remove all image detail so it is just the text from the Windows Form.

Problem is RichTextBoxes do not support drawing the text from them using DrawToBitmap. To fix this issue I am attempting to use a normal textbox. When inputting the address into a new textbox it does not show the returns in the text so it is all bunched up. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You should just need to set the `Multiline` property to true.

Comment: I thought the same thing but it doesn't seem to be working. I also set the AcceptsReturns property to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First all, I'll assume your TextBox's `Multiline` property is set to `true`.

This will work:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, richTextBox1.Lines);
```

This code formats the text in your RichTextBox (in its `Lines` property) so your TextBox will display it properly.

Comment: Okay thanks for the tip. One thing though the data is transferring in between a richtextbox to a mysql database. Is there an alternative for grabbing it from a DataTable row and this working or something similar? It is working directly from a RichTextBox now though but not all my fields come directly from a RichTextBox.

Comment: @GregFroning Glad it helped.  To get the contents of a DataRow into a string with each DataColumn on it's own line try this: `var s = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dt.Rows[dataRowIndex].ItemArray.Cast<string>().ToArray());`

Comment: Okay that is close but that would be for the entire row. What I need is the lines to be displayed from just one item in the data table into the normal textbox.

Comment: Try this:  `object v = dt.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex];`

Comment: I am using that but when displayed in a normal textbox the returns are not there though the text is. Now if I display the same text in a richtextbox the returns are displayed.